# Generating dependencies with Guids for Wix using a batch file

Tags: batch-file, visual-studio-2015, wix

I have a Wix set up project, and I am trying to figure out a way to not be including every dependency manually as I have to it to a bunch of different projects.

I'm trying to use a batch file on pre-build, which looks like

```
@echo off
set TARGETDIRECTORY=%1
set OUTPUTFILE=%2
set PROJDIR=%3
echo Starting Dependency check...
echo ^<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?^> > %OUTPUTFILE%
echo ^<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"^> >> %OUTPUTFILE%
echo   ^<Fragment^> >> %OUTPUTFILE%
echo     ^<ComponentGroup Id="MyWebApiBinaries" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER"^> >> %OUTPUTFILE%

for %%F in (%TARGETDIRECTORY%\*.dll) do (
    echo "-- Adding %%~nxF" 
    echo "-- Calling %PROJDIR%Uuidgen.Exe"
    %PROJDIR%Uuidgen.Exe> %PROJDIR%temp.txt
    set /p aGUID=<%PROJDIR%temp.txt
    del %PROJDIR%temp.txt
    echo "-- Adding %aGUID%"
    echo       ^<Component Id="%%~nxF" Guid="%aGUID%"^> >> %OUTPUTFILE%
    echo                     ^<File  Id="%%~nxF" Name="%%~nxF" Source="%%~dpnxF" Vital="yes" KeyPath="yes" DiskId="1"/^> >> %OUTPUTFILE%
    echo       ^</Component^> >> %OUTPUTFILE%
)

echo     ^</ComponentGroup^> >> %OUTPUTFILE%
echo   ^</Fragment^> >> %OUTPUTFILE%
echo ^</Wix^> >> %OUTPUTFILE%
echo Dependency check done.
```

Got this idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18517549/7180106) except that I needed to add a GUID because I'm installing on inetpub instead of Program Files. So I've included uuidgen.exe into the project to generate a GUID. I call the exe and echo the guid into a temp file, which I later tried to read from, except that it doesn't read it. I've tried this approach on a different batch file and manually calling it and it does read it, so I don't know why it doesn't work here. Basically I'm talking about these two lines:

```
%PROJDIR%Uuidgen.Exe> %PROJDIR%temp.txt
set /p aGUID=<%PROJDIR%temp.txt
```

I've remove the delete to check that the file is generating the guid and being created, and it is there, so I know it would have to be the second line.

I've also tried running

```
for /f %%i in ('"%PROJDIR%\Uuidgen.Exe"') do set GUID=%%i
```

instead of the other two lines, but I don't get the guid on the variable

I know it doesn't get there because I added an echo with the variable, and also `%OUTPUTFILE%` is being generated with an Guid="" (just an empty string/variable). Any ideas why it wouldn't get the guid on the variable?

Comment: `Delayed expansion` issue. I've include an answer about how to solve this without enabling it. But you must pay close attension to other posts, as `delayed expansion` or `variable expansion within a block` have been asked tons of times. Hope it helps.

Comment: Why can't you just use auto generated GUIDs by either omitting the guid attribute or using `Guid="*"`? If you ever auto generate a wxs file for the same components again you may run into issues when upgrading depending on where you schedule removeexistingproducts

Comment: @Brian Sutherland, because outer wise it would error out, i think automatically generated guids only works on programfiles folder. But your concern is valid as well, I hadn't thought about that scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is our old friend `delayed expansion` issue.

There are tons of questions about variable expansion within blocks.

When the command processor finds a block (anything between parentheses), parses it completely and expand variables to the value they have when the block is evaluated. If you update a variable value within a block, you need to enable delayed expansion for the variable to reflect changes made. Also you must change var syntax from  `%var%` to `!var!`.

In your code, `aGUID` var is generated within a `for` block, so it's expanded to the value it holds when the block begins (in your case `empty` or `undefined`). To update value every iteration of the for block you need to enable delayed expansion.

Another workaround is to use a new `for` loop to grab output of `uuidgen.exe` as `for` variables are always expanded inline. This approach gives you another benefit, you won't need a temp file.

> NOTE: Also, you are writing multiple lines to a file, note that

```
>"%output%" (
   for ... do (
     echo(...
     echo(...
   )
)
```

Opens the file only once, whereas

```
   for ... do (
     echo(...>>"%output%"
     echo(...>>"%output%"
   )
```

Opens and closes the file any time >>"%output%" redirection is used, so first one speeds up the block.

> BTW

```
>"%output%" (
   for ... do (
     ...
   )
)
```

is the same as

```
(
   for ... do (
     ...
   )
)>"%output%"
```

Finally, its best practice enclose within quotes both `var name` and `var content` as in

```
set "TARGETDIRECTORY=%~1"
```

to get rid of undesired trailing spaces, also `%~1` means first argument without quotes.

> Not tested. Posible working code

```
@echo off
SetLocal

set "TARGETDIRECTORY=%~1"
set "OUTPUTFILE=%~2"
set "PROJDIR=%~3"

if not "%TARGETDIRECTORY%" EQU "" if not "%OUTPUTFILE%" EQU "" echo Missing argument/s.& exit/B
if not exist "%PROJDIR%Uuidgen.Exe" echo Uuidgen.exe not found or missing argument.& exit/B

echo Starting Dependency check...

>"%OUTPUTFILE%" (
  echo ^<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?^>
  echo ^<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"^>
  echo   ^<Fragment^>
  echo     ^<ComponentGroup Id="MyWebApiBinaries" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER"^>

  for %%F in (%TARGETDIRECTORY%\*.dll) do (
      for /F %%U in ('"%PROJDIR%Uuidgen.Exe"') do (
         echo "-- Adding %%~nxF - GUID %%U" >CON
         echo       ^<Component Id="%%~nxF" Guid="%%U"^>
         echo                     ^<File  Id="%%~nxF" Name="%%~nxF" Source="%%~dpnxF" Vital="yes" KeyPath="yes" DiskId="1"/^>
         echo       ^</Component^>
      )   
  )

  echo     ^</ComponentGroup^>
  echo   ^</Fragment^>
  echo ^</Wix^>
)

echo Dependency check done.
EndLocal
exit /B
```

As all output is redirected to `OUTPUTFILE`, any message you want to be displayed must be then redirected to standard output `>CON`, that's why `echo "-- Adding %%~nxF - GUID %%U" >CON`